# how can I redirect to another html file after being able to store data in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> > > I've first made my web store data on firebase real time database  and
> > >       now I changed it to firestore  but now I'm not quite sure how can I
> > >       redirect after data has been posted to firestore I tried adding  location.href =
> > >       "https://dr-elvic-tengco-web.firebaseapp.com/ThankYou.html"; under
> > >       console.log("Document successfully written!");
> > >        yes it redirects and stores the data
> >
> > and what I noticed it does work when I wait for 2 seconds before I
> >     click the  OK button on the window.alert("Appointment Request Sent!
> >     Please wait for a confirmation on your Email or We'll txt you back!") but noone would wait for 2 seconds before you click "okay" button  ,
> >     right?

```
//I had this code first on firebase realtime database-this worked and redirected
var data = {
            FirstName: firstName,
            LastName: lastName,
            Contact: cPhone,
            Gender: inputGender,
            Birthdate: Bday,
            Address: inputAddress,
            City: inputCity,
            Province: inputState,
            Zip: inputZip,
            Email: exampleInputEmail1,
            Message: inputMessage,
            Clinic: inputClinic
        };
        var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
        firebaseRef.push(data, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log('error');
            } else {
                location.href = "https://dr-elvic-tengco-web.firebaseapp.com/ThankYou.html";
            }
        })
//and now this is the firestore
<script>
//FOR REALTIME DABASE
function getInfo() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    var cPhone = document.getElementById("cPhone").value;
    var exampleInputEmail1 = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value;
    var Bday = document.getElementById("Bday").value;
    var inputGender = document.getElementById("inputGender").value;
    var inputAddress = document.getElementById("inputAddress").value;
    var inputCity = document.getElementById("inputCity").value;
    var inputState = document.getElementById("inputState").value;
    var inputZip = document.getElementById("inputZip").value;
    var inputMessage = document.getElementById("inputMessage").value;
    var inputClinic = document.getElementById("inputClinic").value;
    if (!firstName || !lastName || !cPhone || !exampleInputEmail1 || !Bday || !inputGender || !inputAddress || !inputCity || !inputState || !inputZip || !inputMessage || !inputClinic) {
        window.alert("Please Complete the Form! The Page will Reload For Security Purpose")
        document.getElementById("gbutton").disabled = true;
        document.location.reload()
    } else {
        window.alert("Appointment Request Sent! Please wait for a confirmation on your Email or We'll txt you back!")
        var db = firebase.firestore();

        db.collection("Requests").doc().set({
            FirstName: firstName,
            LastName: lastName,
            Contact: cPhone,
            Gender: inputGender,
            Birthdate: Bday,
            Address: inputAddress,
            City: inputCity,
            Province: inputState,
            Zip: inputZip,
            Email: exampleInputEmail1,
            Message: inputMessage,
            Clinic: inputClinic
            })
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Document successfully written!");
                location.href = "https://dr-elvic-tengco-web.firebaseapp.com/ThankYou.html";
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";` underneath `console.log("Document successfully written!");`

Comment: already did that  , it didn't work
the window.location.href runs quickly and 
what happen is like
its process overlaps the sending of data 
so the data wont be sent to firestore.

Comment: I need something like a callback , on what I did on the first code on firebase realtime  database, and im not sure how to do it.
still studying it

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative by using  setTimeout

.then(function() {
                    console.log("Document successfully written!");

```
                setTimeout(function() {
                    location.href = "https://dr-elvic-tengco-web.firebaseapp.com/ThankYou.html";
                }, 2000);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
```